# Export csv datasource using PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have an excel csv file containing 3 columns and some lines, I want my PHP has an ability to read and export from col2 only. I've tried several tutorials here but none of them could solve my problem.

The csv file contains are:

```
title code image

title1 code1 image1

title2 code2 image2
```

All I want is my PHP file only read and extract values from code column and posted the code as a part of an URL, like this
http://example.com/code/(the code from csv)/

Comment: Post code you've tried so far.

Comment: so far I tried to use this

<?php
$file = fopen("mydata.csv","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  print_r(fgetcsv($file));
  }

fclose($file);
?> 

which is returning with an array, but I still get confused to tell the php just read and print the column 2 only

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for this.

```
$col = 1; //assuming the second column
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        printf('<a href="http://example.com/%s/">link</a>', $data[$col]);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Better yet to enclose in try/catch/finaly block. But that's out of scope here :)